# Google analytics showing all values in negative

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have created report in google analytics application where i can see page views filtered by location. But looks like it is not showing exact number or report as all number in report are in negative format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you created a report with comparison with previous data like previous month vs this month. And the views would have been reduced for this month showing you a negative value. Hope the answer was satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions.. and that worked for me thanks a lot again.